# Best approaches for designing a well-organised ASP.NET application with modularity

Tags: asp.net, modularity, framework-design

I am trying to think about a web application development framework for our product development. I want to build an ASP.NET application which has many sub-modules in it.  My requirements are like:

1. The application will be a suite of different modules like CRM, Bugtracker, Inventory management, Finance management etc.
2. Each Module should have their own DLLs.
3. One project should be for the external container of the application (like the framework) and this project should bring all other modules (of type web application) in the solution to the external container.  (Some thing like we have Frames in HTML).  So we will publish the external container web application only at the end of the day and all other web application projects will be accessed via that.

I would like to have separate DLL for each module so I don't need to fear about the application breaking when I am deploying my single DLL which controls the entire suite.

I am not sure whether my thoughts are in the right direction. The end result I am looking for is a well-maintained, organized, and modular web application suite.

It is ASP.NET web forms, not MVC.  I will use VS2010 for development.

What are the best approaches to do this?

**Edit:**

The term external container means it acts like a master page which has links to various modules and the various modules are not always in the same project. They can be separate project under the same solution. And I am under the impression that, by the end of the day, I will publish that project only and it will bring the various modules to it.

Comment: You need to specify MVC or Web Forms to get a more accurate answer :-)

Comment: @Irish.Thanks for catching that. I updated question

Comment: dotnetnuke is a good example of this situation you're having

Comment: What do you mean by 'the external container of the application'? A portal with links to the other web sites ('modules')?

Comment: @Jeff.Container is like a master page which can bring all modules inside that.

Answer (score 3):

I actually think the best approach would be one that does not over-architect. I'm concerned that it seems you are producing an overall architecture without sufficient reason.

Are these all new modules? Then just start writing the first one. Use best practices that apply to single modules.

Then write the second one. You'll find you want to use things you already wrote in the first module. Great. That's what refactoring is for. Refactor these things out into one or more "library" projects, re-run all your unit tests, then proceed with the second module.

Repeat until all modules are done.

At the end of this process, if you needed the kind of architecture you've outlined, then you'll have it. If you needed less, then you'll have less, and you will not have spent time creating an architecture which is not tied to real-world requirements.

Comment: If all these projects under a soultion,Which one i should publish for deployment ? Should i deploy each one of them indidually and then merge it manually ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to say this is a "best approach" but I would recommend looking over [Dot Net Nuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) (DNN) to get some ideas. This started as the old "I Buy Spy" starter web project that Microsoft distributed to show ASP.NET projects, and it took off from there.

edit:

> *1.The application will be a suite of different modules like CRM, Bugtracker, Inventory management, Finance management etc.*

You can do this with DNN. They're also called "modules" in DNN and Drupal.

> *2.Each Module should have their own DLL's.*

Yes, this is a good idea. And you'll see this sort of thing in several content management systems like DNN and Drupal. This way not all implementations of the same website need to have all modules installed.

We have a significant website that is used to host a "service as a solution" application that we charge for (if you aren't an actuary or accountant you won't have heard of it). The lead developer for the past couple years used an earlier version of DotNetNuke as a model for how to refactor the parts of the application that he was allowed to change.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have suggested DNN would probably work for what you're trying to do.  If you want to completely roll your own naturally I would turn to some sort of combination of a container "Framework" and a bunch of user controls (.ascx).  The container could be as simple as a master page with a menu.  Depending on how flexible you want your design you can prefabricate many different pages, each hosting a different control (separate dll as you wish).  If you want it to be a little more dynamic you can have one content page that will dynamically load at runtime the desired user control into it.  Again this is just a general approach, probably a 30000 feet view into how DNN is implemented anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Name the main project after your company/product and keep it short and simple. You will probably need one or two library projects to support it - these will contain everyday, common logic for such things as [error reporting](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/), Web utility methods, etc.

Next, pick one of your intended [sub-projects](http://msmvps.com/blogs/pauldomag/archive/2006/08/02/106505.aspx) (I don't like the term module in this particular context) and add that to your solution. Whether you are reusing an existing project, or preferably starting from scratch, you will eventually have any common logic in this project moved out to your libraries.

Rinse and repeat. Perhaps take a look at something similar like the [Sueetie](http://sueetie.com/) project which includes several sub-projects like CMS, Blog, Calendar, Forum, etc.

The following article is marked as "outdated" on MSDN but I still think you should take a look at it:

[Structuring Solutions and Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817674.aspx)

Also, something similar from the Patterns and Practices Group:

[Structuring Projects and Solutions in Team Foundation Source Control](http://tfsguide.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Chapter%204%20-%20Structuring%20Projects%20and%20Solutions%20in%20Team%20Foundation%20Source%20Control)